# Sending app facebook request to a non-friend having tokens id

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I explain my case, I'm trying to send FB request to an app to people who is not my friend and I want to do it in name of other person. All these through a java web app I developed (and I'm able to invite my own friends, but not friends of others). For example:

I'm an A user, and I want to invite a B user (who is not my friend, but he's friend of C). And I want to do it in name of C.

It suppossed to have token id of all of them (which wouldn't be a problem since they are my workmates and we just want to do this).

How could I face this approach?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: _"I'm an A user, and I want to invite a B user (who is not my friend, but he's friend of C). And I want to do it in name of C."_ - Not possible. Would be terrible if it was.

Comment: But I mean, to the B user would appear a notification as if C would had invited him, although it's A who does it with a script. Keep in mind that I have full access to all the tokens id or access tokens or whatever from C user.

Comment: Maybe using restfb could be possible?

Comment: No. User-to-user requests can not be send via API, only via the Requests dialog.

Comment: Really? Oh I understood that using restfb you could do it, generating the proper tokens and so on, has this been deprecated?

Comment: I don't know about the older implementation of notifications, but the current one requires the user to send the request actively themselves by using the dialog. And that's a good thing, because everything else would lead to spamming apps.